# How to mimic LEFT JOIN in Siddhi QL

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, siddhi

I'm working with WSO2 DAS. I have 2 streams (Lets call 2 streams as S1 and S2).
I want to join them like SQL Left Join. To more information, When i join S1 and S2 I want output to be consist with every data in the S1 and relevant data from S2.

Since WSO2 Siddhi don't sport to Left Join, How can i get this desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the updated doc here [1]. 
You can only trigger join by one stream by adding `unidirectional` keyword to that stream.

[1]https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#join-stream